# NodeJS: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I run node app.js in nodejs, the error message shows 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'. I have installed all relevant libraries (e.g. request) and have looked at different relevant posts. However, the issue still persists.

Please could you advise how I may fix it. Many thanks!

Windows 10 Home PC
Visual Studio Code

```
//app.js
const geocode = require('./utils/geocode')
const forecast = require('./utils/forecast')

geocode('Boston', (error, data) => {
console.log('Error', error)
console.log('Data', data)
forecast(data.latitude, data.longitude, (error, data) => {
    console.log('Error', error)
    console.log('Data', data)
})


})

// forecast.js
const request = require('request')

const forecast = (latitude, longitude, callback) => {
const url = 
'https://api.darksky.net/forecast/9d1465c6f3bb7a6c71944bdd8548d026/' + 
latitude + ',' + longitude

request({ url: url, json: true }, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
        callback('Unable to connect to weather service!', undefined)
    } else if (response.body.error) {
        callback('Unable to find location', undefined)
    } else {
        callback(undefined, response.body.daily.data[0].summary + ' It is 
currently ' + response.body.currently.temperature + ' degress out. There 
is a ' + response.body.currently.precipProbability + '% chance of rain.')
    }
})
}

module.exports = forecast


// geocode.js
const request = require('request')

const geocode = (address, callback) => {
const url = 'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/' + 
address + '.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYW5kcmV3bWVhZDEiLCJhIjoiY2pvOG8ybW90MDFhazNxcnJ4OTYydzJlOSJ9.njY7HvaalLEVhEOIghPTlw&limit=1'

 request({ url: url, json: true }, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
        callback('Unable to connect to location services!', undefined)
     } else if (response.body.features.length === 0) {
        callback('Unable to find location. Try another search.', 
undefined)
    } else {
        callback(undefined, {
            latitude: response.body.features[0].center[0],
            longitude: response.body.features[0].center[1],
            location: response.body.features[0].place_name
        })
    }
})
}

module.exports = geocode
```

I expect to see Boston, its latitude and its longitude.

Comment: you are talking about this `response.body.features.lengt` right ? 
if yes - can u console it  `response.body.features` and check what u got here

Comment: So, `response.body.features` appears to not exist. Go check what you actually get back from your API request.

Comment: `console.log(response.body)` debug what you got

Answer (score 1):

Before checking the `features` length, you can also check if `features` exists:

```
else if (response.body.features && response.body.features.length === 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like the API return **NULL** ,so there's no **"feature"** in your response body 
in this case u have to check if you are really  getting a response "response.body.features" then check the length .
so your condition be come in your else statement :

`if (response.body.features && response.body.features.length === 0) {}`

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (typeof response.body.features == "undefined")
```

try this

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.